# Set font size in pixels in Corel Draw x7

Tags: corel-draw, font-size

im using Corel Draw x7 and need to use font size in pixels instead of points.
Is there any way to do that?
Thank you

Comment: Hello Ana, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. I don't mean to be rude, but [Let me Google that for you](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sSet+font+size+in+pixels+in+Corel+Draw+x7&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=jbWTVsiuNYiJaKXGpaAE#q=Set+font+size+in+pixels+in+Corel+Draw+x7). This simple search yields just under 16.000 results. Please use a search engine before asking a question here, Thanks for understanding! If you want to know more about this site, have a look at the [help].

Comment: I think it is a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for it a lot, and seems theres is not a way to do that.
The only way i've found was write a letter in uppercase, set the height - not in the font-size - then start typing. This is not very practical - and i don't know if it will make the text-size right -  so i don't think that's the only way..

I also tried to calculate the proportional point value, but it just doesnt work right.

Answer (score 0):

You can type into the text bar where you specify the text size with the pixel affix. For example Instead of typing `12pt` you can type `12px` and it will size the text to 12 pixels (but it will always display in `pt`). Its the same for any other unit of measurement. Like `mm` (milimeters), `cm` (centimeters), `in` or `"` (inches), `ft` or `'` (feet), etc.

You can also make additions and subtractions in the transform toolbar. You could type 12px + 12px and it would automatically add those numbers as 24px. You could even add two different units like, 12mm + 15 inches and it would give you the result in the default unit your ruler is set up as.

You can do this in any box that has a size.